# How to store ListMultimap values in individual arraylists

Tags: java, multimap

/* Sample code*/

```
ListMultimap<String, String> m =ArrayListMultimap.create();

for (String test:m.keySet())
   {
     BaseTest.getLogger().info("Mapped elements:"+ test +"-->"+ m.get(test) );

    }
```

I want to store m.get(test) values in three individual arraylists or array of arraylist, so that i can access them using list.get(1) like..this...any suggestions??

Comment: Why you want `3` individual array lists?

Comment: i'm sorry, not 3, any number of arrraylists that i can create dynamically.

Comment: Can you show exactly what you would like to get out from that map? You're still not clear..

Comment: @ the moment i'm getting output as ..Mapped elements:3Q/2015-->[40067, 20575, 40599] 2Q/2015-->[40067, 20575, 40599] 5Q/2015-->[40067, 20575, 40599], i want to store keyvalues in individual arraylists...i.e i want to store [40067, 20575, 40599] [40067, 20575, 40599] ....these values in individual arraylists. to make it more clear..i want to store m.get(test) values in arraylists, but not in one arraylist, as the loop goes it should store the values in separate arraylists.

Comment: Do you mean like `m.asMap().values()`?

Comment: m.asMap().values()...no idea, but i'm getting a list of values[ x,y,z] like this in each iteration eg. first iteration [a,b,c] 2nd iteration [y.x.u] 3rd [d,r,t]  i want to store each iteration values in different arraylists. so that  i can access them later time by calling individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Collection<List<String>> collectionOfLists = Multimaps.asMap(m).values();
```

Done. Now all the lists are in the `collectionOfLists` collection.

Comment: Appreciate your quick response.But what if i want to store in different arrays...eg. first iteration [a,b,c] 2nd iteration [y.x.u] 3rd [d,r,t] i want to store each iteration values in different arraylists. so that i can access them later time by calling individually.